# A definition of discrete group

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

**Definition**: A discrete group $\Gamma$ is called *residually finite* if  there exist subgroups $\Gamma\supset\Gamma_{1}\supset\Gamma_{2}\supset...$ such that each $\Gamma_{i}$ is a finite-index, normal subgroup of $\Gamma$ and $\bigcap_{n}\Gamma_{n}=\{e\}$(the neutral element of $\Gamma$).

I have two questions about this definition:

1. What is the so called "neutral element" of $\Gamma$?
2. Why is this group called "residually finite"? Is $\Gamma/\Gamma_{n}$ (quotient group) a finite group or somethingelse?

Comment: 1. the unit element

Comment: Residually finite is a rather important property of some groups (most of the usual ones, say), and it can be worded as follows: a group $\;G\;$ is res. fin. iff $$\forall\,1\neq g\in G\;\;\exists\;N_g\lhd G\;,\;\;[G:N_g]<\infty\;,\;\;s.t.\;\;g\notin N_g\;$$  You can prove this is equivalent to what you wrote... **but** you must change your first "exist" by "for all" ...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminology goes back to P. Hall. He called a group $G$ *residually C*, if for any element $g\neq 1$ in $G$ there exists a quotient group $G^*(g)$ belonging to *C*, such that the map $g^*\in G^*(g)$ is not the unit element in $G^*(g)$. Now put for $C$ just the class of finite groups to obtain residually finite groups.

Answer (score 2):

The definition you wrote says taht $\Gamma_i$ is finite-index, which means precisely that $\Gamma/\Gamma_i$ is finite.